# EntityCommandExecutionException при lazy loading

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

При ленивой загрузке вылетает исключение EntityCommandExecutionException, заглянул внутрь исключения, а там написано, что DataReader не закрыт. Я в замешательстве, ведь я юзаю entity.

```
            foreach (User item in Users)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Login");
                Console.WriteLine(item.Login);
                Console.WriteLine("Groups");
                foreach (Group grp in item.Groups)//При обращении тут вылетает исключение
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(grp.Name);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
```

Вот модели данных

```
public class DBContextTest : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOptional<Author>(a => a.Author)
            .WithRequired(a => a.User);
    }
}
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        this.Groups = new List<Group>();
    }
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Author")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string FirsName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string AvatarPath { get; set; }
    public string ResponseQuestion { get; set; }
    public string SecretQuestion { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
}
public class Group
{
    public Group()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        this.Users = new List<User>();
    }
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid? AuthorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }//Автор группы
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

    public Group(string name, Author author)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Author = author;
    }
}
public class Author
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }

    public Author()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Groups = new List<Group>();
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return User.Login;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Причина ошибки: второй запрос (Group) успевает начаться раньше, чем первый прочитает данные (User)" - вольный и сокращенный перевод http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867602/entity-framework-there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-comma

Comment: Общая рекомендация: включение MARS (MultipleActiveResultSets)